# How are emails sent via Workflows in Microsoft CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm Creating a workflow that needs to send the users an email on set events. This I don't have a problem with. However can someone please confirm if you need the local windows SMTP service installed or if I can use another method for it to send the emails.

UPDATE
Ok I've just read about the E-mail Router, just need to find out where it is, and how to get to the configuration settings.

UPDATE

Update 2
Right, Iv'e looked into it and the e-mail router configuration is not used on this CRM set-up, it used an Outlook Add-in which I cant find a lot of into on.

However it appears to work flawlessly. 
end update 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two options, one which uses the SMTP or exchange. And another which is an outlook plugin. Which syncs the emails with the owners outlook and then sends out the emails.

EDIT
So the two options which both work are:

1. Email Router - This appears to be the standard and can use various email servers
2. Outlook add-in - This sends email based on the owner/email settings in the CRM record.
                    This works with any email CRM wants to send, and even works with workflows.

I've not got to the bottom of why the outlook add-in has been used at this site, however the workflow functions appear to run without problem, and seamlessly to the owner/user.

end edit

Comment: The workflow is a separate tool. And works against the CRM server only. The mails are to be sent from the server only. With no connection or communication to ant outlook client whatsoever.

Comment: The way how I'm told the Outlook Add-in works, is by queuing up any emails that need to be sent from CRM and sync. with their owners Outlook, Which are then sent on. The server I'm working can only send email in this way, as the other way (exchange/smtp) has not been enabled/configured.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Microsoft CRM uses Exchange server to send out emails. Haven't you configured this during setup?

Comment: The system was setup long before I started working on it. Just wanted to know where to check on their live system to confirm that everything was setup correctly before I roll out the new workflows. (If you haven't guessed already I'm new to CRM)

Comment: Mine is at 

c:\profgram files\microsoft crm\tools\microsoft.crm.tools.workflowmanager.exe

Simply add action (of type:Email) and fill in the details and the based template

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the Email Router is the way to enable outbound emails from Dynamics CRM.  If you haven't done so already, I strongly encourage you to download the [Dynamics CRM Implementation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1CEB5E01-DE9F-48C0-8CE2-51633EBF4714&displaylang=en#filelist).  You can jump right to the section called "Planning e-mail integration" to read about it.

What you need to do is configure the e-mail router to operate with a POP3/SMTP server.  You can use Windows Server's SMTP service for that.  You can use almost any service - i have configured it to work with my gmail account, for instance.

Here are three good articles that you can read to learn more about the e-mail router.

- [What's New in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 E-Mail Integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/archive/2008/01/29/what-s-new-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-e-mail-integration.aspx)
- [Dynamics CRM 4.0 E-mail Integration Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/crm/archive/2008/02/07/crm-4-0-e-mail-integration-overview.aspx)
- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM: How to configure the On-premise and Online E-mail Router in different deployment scenarios](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8ea05b4e-825a-4db1-ad59-d894aa5ef33e&DisplayLang=en)

Now when you configure an email from a workflow, CRM will automatically forward it out through the router to your SMTP email account.

Comment: We have another team that looks after the standard stuff like CRM. However its still important for me to know so thanks for the guide.

Comment: While your'e right for what would account for 99% of all setups, there still is an Outlook Add-in option that allows emails to work without the usual method.